# Sending Emails on localhost for Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I am trying to test some email sending from my localhost. I'd like to use an external SMTP server for this matter. I am using Cent OS 6.I can't find the useful topics related for this? Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Run [mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog). It's super easy to install with [tag:docker].

Comment: thanks, I 'll try it.